# JavaScript is synchronous then why we need callback function

Tags: javascript, callback

since javascript is synchronous then why do we need callback function,

in the below picture both code can same thing

[image]

Comment: Your example has no logic that benefits from asynchronous behavior, so the only thing you gain by having a callback function is that it allows you to parameterize the function's behavior.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen what you mean by Parameterize

Answer (score 2):

As @Meno-101 rightly said, you're looking at the trivial function invocation utility of callbacks, they're rather used for asynchronous calls. In asynchronous calls we wait for some data to arrive and then invoke a function, you won't see a difference when you're being presented with the result in an instant. `setTimeout` is one easy way to replicate such a situation;

> Callbacks are generally used when the function needs to perform events before the callback is executed, or when the function does not (or cannot) have meaningful return values to act on, as is the case for Asynchronous JavaScript (based on timers) or XMLHttpRequest requests. [Checkout the deets here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming))

But if we're are bent on using it synchronously , I could only come up with this code:
[image]

This made the code reusable which isn't possible the other way, we'd have to write different definitions of same function for `disp()` and `disp1()` to function.

Answer (score 1):

You’re just confusing callback’s purpose with a function invocation purpose.

Callbacks are used in the case of web requests, reading/writing to files, or maybe even just waiting for some reason the programmer only know why, take this example:

```js
setTimeout(()=> console.log(“hello”), 3000)
```

There must be a reason for you to have this in your code, what ever it’s you don’t want all the page to hang up on the user.

And, I do recommend you look for function call stack if you’re just starting off.